JS css styling on background Image does not change and shows the same gradient color, while it should alternate between two gradients
I have tried to use this code for changing the background color of according to the number being displayed. If it's even a different gradient and if it's odd another different gradient. Its only showing the first gradient and not the second one
HTML Code :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>JS Updating Styles</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body id="bg">
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <h1 id="title"></h1>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>


CSS Code :
code {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: lightseagreen;
}

#bg {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #051937, #A8EB12); */
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #845EC2, #FF6F91); */
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 44px;
}

JS Code :
const element = document.getElementById("title");
var bgImg = document.getElementById("bg");
var i = 10;
setInterval(function () {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    bgImg.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(45deg, #845EC2, #FF6F91)";
    console.group("even");
  } else {
    bgImg.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(45deg, #051937, #A8EB12);";
    console.group("odd");
  }
  element.innerHTML = i--;
  console.log(i);

  if (i < 0) {
    element.innerHTML = 0;
  }
}, 1500);


I want that with each odd number and even number the background gradient should be different. But its is not changing.

Typo: remove the semicolon at the end of "linear-gradient(45deg, #051937, #A8EB12);"

if (i % 2 == 0) { bgImg.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(45deg, #845EC2, #FF6F91)";  console.group("even");  } else { bgImg.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(45deg, #051937, #A8EB12);";  console.group("simple");  } Focusing on this part of the code, you made a mistake closing the second gradient.  So you can use "linear-gradient(45deg, #051937, #A8EB12);";  not written at the end ;"; actually used ";  should have been used.
